# Use of QtWidgets crashes Toon Boom Harmony while trying to use variable/object from another scope

Tags: javascript, qt, ecmascript-3

So I'm trying to create some kind of animation pipeline tool that will handle saving, loading, etc. All of this should be a separate tab in a tab widget.

For this purpose I have a base widget class and then the functional widget itself, which inherits from the base widget.

`WidgetBase` class:

```
var FrosyaWidgetBase = function(asUiFilePath, asWidgetName) {
    this._msWidgetName = asWidgetName;
    this._msUiFilePath = asUiFilePath;
}
 
FrosyaWidgetBase.prototype.loadUi = function() {

}

FrosyaWidgetBase.prototype.setupSignals = function() {

}

FrosyaWidgetBase.prototype.setWidgetLayout = function(aWidget) {
    FrosyaWidgetBase.prototype.setLayout(aWidget);
}

FrosyaWidgetBase.prototype.getWidgetName = function() {
    return this._msWidgetName;
}
```

`SaveLoadWidget` class:

```
var FrosyaSaveLoadWidget = function() {
    FrosyaWidgetBase.call(this, MEL_FROSYA_RES + "/ui/SaveLoadWidget.ui", "SaveLoadWidget");

    this._msWidgetTitle = "Save/Load";
    this._maProjectList = {};
    this._mWidgetUi = UiLoader.load(this._msUiFilePath);

    var _xmlReader = new XMLReader(MEL_FROSYA_CFG + "/ProjectPaths.xml");
    _xmlReader.read();
    projArray = _xmlReader.findAllElelemntsByNodeName("project");
    for (var i = 0; i < projArray.length; i++) {
        var projName = _xmlReader.getNodeAttributeValue(projArray[i], "name");
        var projPath = _xmlReader.getNodeAttributeValue(projArray[i], "path");
        var projType = _xmlReader.getNodeAttributeValue(projArray[i], "type");

        this._maProjectList[projName] = ProjectFactory(projPath, projName, projType);
    }

    this.addTreeWidgetRoot = function(asName) {
        treeItem = new QTreeWidgetItem(this._mWidgetUi.SearchTreeWidget);
        treeItem.setText(0, asName);
        return treeItem;
    }

    this.addTreeWidgetChild = function(asName) {

    }

    this.loadUi();
    this.setupSignals();
}

FrosyaSaveLoadWidget.prototype = Object.create(FrosyaWidgetBase.prototype);

FrosyaSaveLoadWidget.prototype.startSearch = function() {
    this._mWidgetUi.ProjectSearch.blockSignals(true);
    
    const searchAssetType = this._mWidgetUi.TypeComboBox.currentText;
    const selectedItem = this._mWidgetUi.ProjectComboBox.currentText;
    const searchText = this._mWidgetUi.ProjectSearch.text;
    const project = this._maProjectList[selectedItem];

    var searchResult = project.findAsset(searchText, searchAssetType);
    for (var i = 0; i < searchResult.length; i++) {
        this.addTreeWidgetRoot(searchResult[i]);
    }

    this._mWidgetUi.ProjectSearch.blockSignals(false);
}

FrosyaSaveLoadWidget.prototype.setupSignals = function() {
    this._mWidgetUi.ProjectSearch.returnPressed.connect(this, this.startSearch);
}

FrosyaSaveLoadWidget.prototype.loadUi = function() {
    for (var proj in this._maProjectList) {
        this._mWidgetUi.ProjectComboBox.addItem(proj);
    }

    this._mWidgetUi.TypeComboBox.addItem("Animation");
    this._mWidgetUi.TypeComboBox.addItem("L-out");
}

FrosyaSaveLoadWidget.prototype.widget = function() {
    return this._mWidgetUi;
}
```

As you can see, widget ui loads via UiLoader, and then I setup `returnPressed` signal which leads to the function using project class `findAsset` method from another JS file.

`project.findAsset` method:

```
TVProject.prototype.findAsset = function(asSearchText, asSearchAssetType) {
    var result = []

    if (asSearchAssetType == "Animation") {
        result = this.findAnimationScene(asSearchText);
    } else if (asSearchAssetType == "L-Out") {
        result = this.findLayoutScene(asSearchText);
    }

    return result;
}

TVProject.prototype.findLayoutScene = function(asSearchText) {
    return;
}

TVProject.prototype.findAnimationScene = function(asSearchText) {
    var srIndx = (asSearchText.match(/sr\d+/)) ? asSearchText.match(/sr\d+/)[0] : "";
    var epIndx = (asSearchText.match(/ep\d+/)) ? asSearchText.match(/ep\d+/)[0] : "";
    var scIndx = (asSearchText.match(/sc\d+/)) ? asSearchText.match(/sc\d+/)[0] : "";

    if (srIndx && epIndx && scIndx) {
        var dir = this.getAnimationPath().path() + "/" + srIndx + "/" + epIndx + "/" + scIndx;
        if (isDir(dir)) {
            return [dir];
        }
        return [];
    }

    var srIndxHasExactValue = true;
    var epIndxHasExactValue = true;
    var scIndxHasExactValue = true;

    if (!srIndx) {
        srIndx = "sr001";
        srIndxHasExactValue = false;
    }

    if (!epIndx) {
        epIndx = "ep01";
        epIndxHasExactValue = false;
    }

    if (!scIndx) {
        scIndx = "sc01";
        scIndxHasExactValue = false;
    }

    var firstLevelDirs  = [srIndx];
    var secondLevelDirs = [epIndx];
    var thirdLevelDirs  = [scIndx];
    var result = [];

    if (!srIndxHasExactValue) {
        firstLevelDirs = this.getAnimationPath().entryList(QDir.Filters(QDir.Dirs, QDir.NoDotAndDotDot, QDir.NoSymLinks));
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < firstLevelDirs.length; i++) {
        var srDir = new QDir(this.getAnimationPath().path() + "/" + firstLevelDirs[i]);
        secondLevelDirs = [epIndx];

        if (!epIndxHasExactValue) {
            secondLevelDirs = srDir.entryList(QDir.Filters(QDir.Dirs, QDir.NoDotAndDotDot, QDir.NoSymLinks));
        }
        
        for (var j = 0; j < secondLevelDirs.length; j++) {
            var epDir = new QDir(srDir.path() + "/" + secondLevelDirs[j]);
            thirdLevelDirs = [scIndx];
            
            if (!scIndxHasExactValue) {
                thirdLevelDirs = epDir.entryList(QDir.Filters(QDir.Dirs, QDir.NoDotAndDotDot, QDir.NoSymLinks));
            }
            
            for (var k = 0; k < thirdLevelDirs.length; k++) {
                result.push(epDir.path() + "/" + thirdLevelDirs[k]);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Problem:**

With the first run of the script all works just fine, but when I close the the widget window and rerun the script, Toon Boom immediately crashes with error:

> QThread: destroyed while thread is still running

The same happens if try to access `MessageLog` object from the connected function. Actually this particular case can be solved with adding `MessageLog` to the function scope like:

```
this._console = MessageLog.
```

Also, if I try to run the script for the first time using the Toon Boom debugger, it will also throw an error like:

> Uncaught exception at Project.js:200: TypeError: Result of expression 'QDir' [undefined] is not an object

How can I add objects into another object scope or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. You need to work with `QDialog` widgets only. I think because it's the only widget that have [`exec`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdialog.html#exec) method which is runs separate loop instead of working in Toon Boom loop. So, all the subwidgets may be any type you want, but the **main one should be QDialog**.